# A query on PostgreSQL not working as it should

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created 2 tables, one for drivers names and the other for their corresponding vehicles, my exercise is to pick out the driver whose registration date is less than a month away, the query should pick out only one driver but what happens is that it lists all the 3 drivers although the condition is not applied in the other 2 :

Creating schema:

```
create table drivers (
  id serial primary key,
  first_name varchar,
  last_name varchar
);

create table vehicles (
  id serial primary key,
  make varchar,
  model varchar,
  registration_date date,
  driver_id integer references drivers(id)
);
INSERT INTO drivers (id,first_name, last_name) VALUES (1,'John', 'Doe'),(2,'Michael', 'Doe'),(3,'Jane', 'Fonda');
INSERT INTO vehicles (make,model,registration_date, driver_id) VALUES ('Volkswagen', 'Jetta','2012-10-23',1),('Skoda', 'Octavia','2011-03-01',2),('Opel', 'Meriva','2015-08-01',3);
```

Query:

```
select d.first_name , d.last_name , v.make
from drivers d
join vehicles v
on v.driver_id= d.id
where v.registration_date::DATE  - CURRENT_DATE::DATE  < 30;
```

Result:

```
first_name  last_name   make
John         Doe        Volkswagen
Michael      Doe        Skoda
Jane         Fonda      Opel
```

Comment: look at your dates. You are subtracting the current date from a super old date. So, negative 3,000 days is less than 30. You will want to perhaps look only at month part, assuming that registration is annual.

Comment: Thanks , I spotted that mistake , but even when adjsuting the registration date to be in 2021 , samae result , besides when applying the condition , I need to omit the year from the registration date and compare mere days only

Comment: I think there are several ways to do this. Without better understanding the data, this option may not be the best and would ignore those past due.... just depends on your data and what you want to report:  where abs(v.registration_date::DATE  - CURRENT_DATE::DATE)  < 30

Answer (score 1):

A sort of convoluted example:

```
select 
  registration_date, d.first_name , d.last_name , v.make
from 
   drivers d
join 
   vehicles v
on 
   v.driver_id= d.id
where 
   make_date(extract(year from current_date)::int, extract(month from  v.registration_date)::int, extract(day from v.registration_date)::int ) - current_date  
between 0 and 29;

registration_date | first_name | last_name |    make    
-------------------+------------+-----------+------------
 2012-10-23        | John       | Doe       | Volkswagen
```

Using `make_date` and `extract` from [Date/time operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html). I could see turning the `make_date(...)` portion into a function.

Comment: Thank you so much